# How To Constrains Google OAuth To A Specific Google Apps Domain

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-apps-for-education

I have a Java web application that uses Google OAuth for authentication (with this API : http://goo.gl/6wWyT3) and it works fine. However, I need a way to allow only users from a certain Google Apps for Education domain e.g mike@wdu.edu.ng to be able to gain access to the app using Google's OAuth. How do I go about this ??

Answer (score 0):

send users off to Google with a parameter `hd=<domain.com>` in the authorization request (by modifying buildLoginUrl) to skip the account chooser screen and upon return, check that the claims returned from Google contain the `hd` claim with a value `<domain.com>` in getUserInfoJson to enforce the access requirement

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It led to the solution, which I implemented thus : public String buildLoginUrl() {
  
  final GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl();
  
  return url.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).setState(getStateToken()).set("hd", "domain.com").build();
 }

Comment: Is it possible to constrain it to more than a single domain ? Will a coma separated list (string) of domains work ?

Comment: not that I know of, otherwise you'll have to just omit the hd parameter from the authorization request and rely on the account chooser screen that pops up for the domain selection part; notice that you will have to enforce the actual restriction on the getUserInfoJson anyway, any request parameter addition is just a UX thing with not serving any security purpose

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to understand the point of passing hd=<domain.com> if one has to check it again when Google returns the response? Google anyway returns hd value if you pass hd parameter or not.